# How to sort lines by deleting multiple entries in first field but keep the entry with highest value using sort and awk commands

Tags: sorting, awk

I  have a file which has two columns where the first field has multiple identical entries each with a corresponding value.

```
hi           3 
hello        4 
who          3 
hello        6 
hi           7 
who          9
```

Now I want to sort the lines resulting in unique entries (first field) while  holding the highest corresponding value from the input file. It should be something like this.

```
hi    7 
hello 6 
who   9
```

How can I accomplish the task using sort and awk? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
awk '$2>array[$1]{array[$1]=$2} END{for (i in array) print i, array[i]}'
```

**Test**

```
$  cat input
hi 3
hello 4
who 3
hello 6
hi 7
who 9 

$ awk '$2>array[$1]{array[$1]=$2} END{for (i in array) print i, array[i]}' input
hello 6
hi 7
who 9
```

Comment: Hi ... Thanks a lot for your answer.. Got the result striaght away. :-)